# Getting data from stdClass Object in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to get balance from my array . here is the array below

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2372
    [cash_memo_id] => 2373
    [date] => 2021-02-24
    [customer_name] => A.T Corporation
    [customer_code] => 9
    [ship_to] => A.T Corporation
    [truck_no] => 1
    [total] => 328080.30
    [total_due] => 328080.30
    [balance] => 328080.30
)
```

This is the query below

```
$cartdata = DB::table('cart_manage')
    ->where('customer_code',$customer_code)
    ->first();
```

I am trying to get balance value using this way ...

```
$cartdata->balance;
```

but I greeting error
Trying to get property 'balance' of non-object
Please help me .
Thanks to All

Comment: Please debug what's in `$cartdata` before accessing the property: `dump($cartdata)`

Comment: `first()` can return `null` which would not be an object; the query didn't return a result ... also that isn't an array you are showing but an object

Comment: {#568 ▼
  +"id": 2372
  +"cash_memo_id": "2373"
  +"date": "2021-02-24"
  +"customer_name": "A.T Corporation"
  +"customer_code": "9"
  +"customer_address": "Rajbari"
  +"customer_phone": "017"
  +"ship_to": "A.T Corporation"
  +"truck_no": "1"
  +"total": "328080.30"
  +"total_due": "328080.30"
  +"balance": "328080.30"
}

Comment: use gettype( $cartdata) to get the type of the variable being returned

Comment: Where are you performing the query and where are you accessing `$cartdata`? If this is a controller method, please can you show the code for the entire method.